# Overfull \hbox (1.38991pt too wide) in paragraph at lines, Latex warning even though PDF is getting generated

Tags: latex, tex, pdflatex

This below latex code has warning saying `Overfull \hbox (1.38991pt too wide) in paragraph at lines`; pdf is getting generated without any issue, I am trying to find out where exactly I am making a mistake to see that warning.

Latex code1:

```
\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
```

Latex code2:

```
%\section{Literature Review}%
\begin{frame}{OBJECTIVE}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
   
    \begin{tabular}{ p{3cm}|p{7cm}}
     \hline
     \vspace{1pt}
    Title & “CompaRob:The shopping cart assistance robot"  \textit{’ Int. J. Distrib. Sensor Netw., vol. 12,no. 2, Feb. 2016, Art. no. 4781280.} \\
     \hline
     \vspace{6mm}
     Methodology & 
     \begin{itemize}
         \item Radio and ultrasound signals
         \item Provide freedom of movements for elderly people
     \end{itemize}\\
     \hline
     \vspace{1pt}
    Demerit & 
    \begin{itemize}
        \item  Not able to show how to find a product
       
    \end{itemize}\\
     \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: It's a warning, not an error, that's why you get a PDF. At 1.4pt you probably need to look closely for the one line that's too long, but for bigger numbers you'll have lines extending far to the right. It would be very cumbersome to scroll to a 500 page pdf to find all those, so LaTeX reports them. Often you can fix this by wording some sentences differently. If your table causes this, try smaller columns. Or adjust page borders (see the geometry package).

Comment: @Robert Don't use the commands from geometry to adjust the margins in a beamer document. `beamer` has its own interface for this

Comment: @Robert And you will still get a pdf for most non-catastrophic errors, that's not a good argument

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Yes, I was just explaining why you get a PDF when you also get something that looks like errors. It wasn't an argument for or against anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not enough space to fit 10 cm worth of columns *and* the default padding before and after the columns. Either remove the padding by using `@{}p{2.9cm}|p{7cm}@{}` or make the columns a bit smaller:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}


%\section{Literature Review}%
\begin{frame}{OBJECTIVE}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
   
    \begin{tabular}{ p{2.9cm}|p{7cm}}
     \hline
     \vspace{1pt}
    Title & “CompaRob:The shopping cart assistance robot"  \textit{’ Int. J. Distrib. Sensor Netw., vol. 12,no. 2, Feb. 2016, Art. no. 4781280.} \\
     \hline
     \vspace{6mm}
     Methodology & 
     \begin{itemize}
         \item Radio and ultrasound signals
         \item Provide freedom of movements for elderly people
     \end{itemize}\\
     \hline
     \vspace{1pt}
    Demerit & 
    \begin{itemize}
        \item  Not able to show how to find a product
       
    \end{itemize}\\
     \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}

 


\end{document}
```